# Safe Blender Download Mirrors

Tags: installation

[blender.org](https://blender.org) seems to be [down](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/blender.org.html) as of now. And I could not find a list of trustworthy download mirrors. Does anyone have such links in handy?

Comment: Blender's websites are currently offline due to a DoS attack which saturates the full data rate of its link. It started around 15:15 (UTC+1). Currently there aren't any official mirrors as far as I'm aware. Developers would use the local copy of the git repository to create their builds. Users will have to wait until the attack has stopped.

Comment: If you have Steam, you can get Blender through that

Comment: @RobertGützkow Okay, stop right there. How the hell do you know these things? :)

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ Several developers reported connection issues and Danny McGrath ([troubled](https://twitter.com/troubledaemon)) who is Blender's admin confirmed that a DoS was in progress. For more information see: https://blender.chat/channel/blender-coders

Comment: @stphnl329 right, forgot about Steam. If you're on Linux then you can also download it through the package manager of your distribution.

Comment: If you're on Windows you can also download it from the Windows Store. For some reason I completely forgot about these options since I'm compiling my own version for a while.

Comment: [We're back online (at least for now).](https://twitter.com/tonroosendaal/status/1222980229150519305?s=19)

Comment: At the time of writing, the official mirrors are listed in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/blender_org/status/1223045762478723072).

Comment: @RobertGützkow DoS again. Is there a mirror for the docs, too? (https://twitter.com/tonroosendaal/status/1242832216285208579)

Comment: @handle I don't know of an official one. During the last DoS some people shared links to their self-hosted docs on [blender-coders](https://blender.chat/channel/blender-coders). Might be worth asking there.

Comment: My first comment was incorrect, there is a public list of official mirrors. They are listed on [this page](https://www.blender.org/about/website/).

Comment: https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/blender/release/ is down again Try https://download.blender.org/release/
Worked for me. Tobi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows:
https://mirror.clarkson.edu/blender/release/Blender2.81/blender-2.81a-windows64.msi

Windows - Portable (.zip): https://mirror.clarkson.edu/blender/release/Blender2.81/blender-2.81a-windows64.zip

macOS:
https://mirror.clarkson.edu/blender/release/Blender2.81/blender-2.81a-macOS.dmg

Linux:
https://mirror.clarkson.edu/blender/release/Blender2.81/blender-2.81a-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar.bz2

I got these links using the tool Wayback Machine (https://web.archive.org/). It has a saved Blender download page from few days ago (https://web.archive.org/web/20200125185852/https://www.blender.org/download/). When you click on download it appears to you a "thank you" page, then there is a link on a text on the bottom of that page ("Your download should begin automatically. If it doesn't, click here to retry."), which leads to an official mirror download. You click on it and the download will start.

Comment: Great find! Learning something new today. I didn't know that the Clarkson University hosts an official mirror of [all releases](https://mirror.clarkson.edu/blender/release/). You can also get the [source code](https://mirror.clarkson.edu/blender/source/) for each release.

Comment: Never thought DDoS attack would actually make it *easier* to get Blender... :).

Comment: The clarkson.edu link is running really slow this morning, probably due to the 3.0 release. The official mirrors link https://www.blender.org/about/website/ let me pull from Europe which was actually much faster today.

Answer (score 6):

In case [www.blender.org](https://blender.org/) is completely offline, you can also download it from the following official sources:

- [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/Blender/) (requires local installation of Steam)
- [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/blender/9pp3c07gtvrh)
- [Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/blender)
- [One of the official mirrors](https://www.blender.org/about/website/)

Alternatively, if you're a software developer, you can clone the Blender repositories and [build it yourself](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender). This will allow you to compile Blender from past commits and releases locally, if you have the required dependencies installed, even when all Blender websites are offline. In case you're planning to prepare for potential outages, you may want to clone the repositories for the manual and API documentation as well. Blender also has a [mirror of the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/blender/blender).

When the [official website](https://www.blender.org/download/) is reachable, but the download is slow or fails, you can use the *click here to retry* link at the bottom of the "Thank you"-page. This will use one of the mirrors that is [geographically close to you](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BO/browse/master/themes/bthree/functions.php%24259), thereby reducing round-trip times.

[image]